# Lost recovery partition

Tags: windows, partitioning

I have a new asus windows 7 laptop. Using the "AI Recovery" tool, I deleted the 8 gig windows recovery partition.

Now the Disk Management utility is showing my disk to be 111.79 GB rather than the 119.24 it was before. I seem to have lost the space that the recovery partition was taking up, rather than having it returned to use.

I'd like my 8 GB back, it's only a 128 GB disk.

--Edit--
Maybe it's not a 128 GB disk, maybe it's a 120 GB disk. I was comparing it against an identical laptop, except the HDDs are different. One is an ADATA XM11 128GB (114472MB) and the other is a SanDisk SSD U100 (122103MB). 8GB difference. Perhaps I didn't have as much space as I thought. Anyone with an XM11 want to tell me how many MB it's got in it. ADATA aren't telling.

DiskPart says
Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset

---

Partition 1    Primary            111 GB  1024 KB

Comment: If you are unsure about your notebook specs, then just check the specpaper, it should tell you how much space your NB has.

Comment: Crank up `diskpart`.  Run the `list disk` and `list partition` commands.  Put the results in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Go to control panel -> administrative tools -> computer management -> storage -> disk management:

You should see all your partitions there, including the "lost" unallocated space.
Click on your systemdrive (probably C:)  and there on *extend volume*. You will see a wizard which will guide you thru the process to add your lost space to your current partition(the C: partition).

Comment: Nope. First thing I tried. Can't extend. I shrank and then extended. Still the same size.

Comment: @Spike why did you shrink it in the first place? Make a screen please.

Comment: I deleted the recovery partition by accident. That tool deleted it when I clicked a checkbox. (Who writes a GUI like that?) I shrank it because I thought it might make the OS rescan the disk. Now I think it maybe it isn't lost, that the 128GB disk is only 120GB.

Comment: @Spike if you deleted the partition, then there should be some unallocated space, or like you said you are mixing the numbers a bit. Post a pic or your NB specs, that should make it clear.

Comment: I've been looking for the specs on the HDD. The ADATA XM11 is not a consumer available product. They don't list the specs on the website.

Comment: @Spike yeah, I checked, too but your notebook specs should say how much GB your HDD has.

Answer (score -1):

You can recover deleted partitions and much more by using TestDisk. You can find the procedure on how to do this here:

http://blog.eddsn.com/2011/02/how-to-recover-lost-or-deleted-partitions/

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation with TestDisk development group or the weblog you linked to in your answer, if there is one.

Comment: The blog is mine. No affiliation with TestDisk. I saw that there were multiple questions on the problem with deleted partitions/data that I solved myself some time earlier which is described in the post on my blog.

Comment: There are a few things here that are usually frowned upon. One is promotion without disclosure. Unless you overdo it, it's not a problem as long as you disclose it. Please start mentioning that it's your blog. The other is "link only answers", i.e. answers that become useless once a link goes dead. It'd be helpful if you could add a short summary to your answer, or quoted relevant blog post parts.

Comment: Ok, I'll take care of that next time. :)